# Using JQuery load method to render component inside a div. How to render multiple components in divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is the code I am using. I am unable to render components in div with same class name, but its strange, if I am using divs, one with id and one with class, it's rendering fine. If I add the 3rd one, it's not rendering.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>React App</title>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div class="team-container"></div>
        <div id="a" ></div>
        <div id="b" ></div>
        <div id="c" ></div> 
        <div id="d" class= "team"></div>
    
    <script>
            function renderComponent(id){
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $(id).load(
              "private component url link"
            ); // Handler for .ready() called.
          });
        }
    
        //renderComponent("#a")
        renderComponent("#d")
        renderComponent(".team-container")
    
        </script>  
      </body>
    </html>
```